# Using the logic from impulse functions in reverse

Tags: real-analysis, dirac-delta

Let $$\delta_c(t)=\begin{array}{cc}
  \big\{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & c<t&t<-c \\
      \frac{1}{2c} & -c\leq t\leq c \\
    \end{array}
\end{array}$$
Then $\lim_{c\to0^+}\delta_c(t)$ is the Dirac Delta function for $\mathbb R^2$

However if we let $L=\lim_{c\to+\infty}$ for shorthand $$L\delta_c(t)=\begin{array}{cc}
  \big\{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & L(c)<t&t<L(-c) \\
      L(\frac{1}{2c}) & L[-c\leq t\leq c] \\
\end{array}
    \end{array}=\begin{array}{cc}
  \big\{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & L(c)<t&t<L(-c) \\
      0 & L[-c\leq t\leq c] \\
\end{array}    
\end{array}$$
Which in English means that $t<-\infty$, the limit is $0$, and that $t>\infty$ the limit is $0$, and since these regions are absurd, we can disregard them. However for for $-\infty\le t\le\infty$ the limit is $0$, so for all real numbers, the limit is $0$, so the limit as a whole is $0$, so $L\delta_c(t)=0$

And we know that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_c(t)dt=\int_{-c}^c\frac1{2c}dt=1$$

But consider$$L\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta_c(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty L\delta_c(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}0dt=0$$
 and $$L\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta_c(t)dt=L1=1$$

So what happened? I know that I messed up somewhere but I don't see it. I'm assuming the error is where the limit is $0$ but I don't see where I messed up unless $L\frac1{2c}\ne0$

Comment: If $c$ is a positive number, the double inequality $c<t<-c$ doesn't make much sense... Well, it's a more or less meaningful inequality, but the set of $t$ that satisfy it is empty.

Comment: @zipirovich I assumed it would mean$-c<t$ Union $t<c$ I'll fix it when I'm on my computer and I can see what I'm doing more clearly.

Comment: No, a double inequality $a<b<c$ means that $a<b$ **and** $b<c$, and that "**and**" makes it the **intersection** of the solutions of the two inequalities. By transitivity of "$<$", it also implies that $a<c$ -- otherwise, it's either meaningless or false. Besides, you're contradicting yourself: I'm pretty sure that in the second line of the piecewise definition of $\delta_c(t)$, when you wrote "$-c\le t\le c$", you meant that $t\in[-c,c]$; but then why would you presume a *different* interpretation for the same kind of statement "$c<t<-c$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing by "$L=\lim_{c\to+\infty}$" you're just introducing a shorthand notation for taking this limit, like a limit operator for the pointwise limit with respect to $t$. In that case the mistake is here:
$$\lim_{c\to+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta_c(t)\,dt \color{red}{=} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lim_{c\to+\infty} \delta_c(t)\,dt.$$
(I rewrote it using the usual limit notation.)

In general, you can't switch a limit with an integral, i.e. in general
$$\lim_{c\to c_0} \int_a^b f_c(t)\,dt \neq \int_a^b \lim_{c\to c_0} f_c(t)\,dt.$$
The equality is guaranteed to hold if the functions $f_c(t)$ converge **uniformly** to $f(t)=\lim\limits_{c\to c_0} f_c(t)$ on the interval $[a,b]$. But I suspect that the convergence of $\delta_c(t)$ to $\lim\limits_{c\to+\infty} \delta_c(t)=0$ (the identically zero function) on $t\in(-\infty,+\infty)$ is not uniform.

Comment: Could you explain what makes something uniform?

Comment: @JacobClaassen: From a quick online search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence or http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/m500f09/Uniform%20Convergence.pdf